# Gayatri mantra for Lagna

Tags: gayatri-mantra

Can someone shed light on the Gayatri Mantra for lagna.
By lagna I don't mean the house where lagna is present in horoscope, like scorpio, leo etc.
The mantra goes something like this Om Lagnaye ....

Any help with scriptural references would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't ask same question repeatedly. It is not allowed

Comment: Duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/33879/6981

Comment: Pls wait for answers to be posted under your other question :) @DolaGovinda

Comment: @Krishna Swetha, the link you provided as duplicate lans on same page as my question. Could you pls guide me to correct link

Comment: You asked same question twice. Hence your second question is marked duplicate of first question. In stack exchange, questions which are duplicate of previous question will be closed as duplicate. If you want to add anything in question then please use "edit" button. And same user should not ask same question repeatedly, you have to wait till that someone will answer. For more information please visit [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help)